# After adding loop cut bunch of ngons appears (cylinder)

Tags: modeling, loop

Why is this happening? I never had problem like that before. Scale is applied. Its really small cylinder (about 0.5 cm radius and 64 parts)
[image]

Comment: Your top face circle has more verts than the vertical faces. Share your .blend
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: But how it has more verts at the top if it is just plain generic cilinder with radius of 0.5 and 64 segments? Strange.

Comment: In your image, I can only count 10 vetical edges, but many more verts in the top circle. Do you have any modifiers? Perhaps there is a bunch of extra edges around the circle? Try Merge by Distance?